# Cascade deleting all relations asp.net core fluent api

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

For example, I have a table with fields:

```
Id, Name  ParentId 
1   TEST  NULL
2   TEST2 1
3   TEST3 2
```

When I try to remove record with Id = 1 I need cascade delete all of them (using parentId like a key). 
How can I do it? is it possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible. SqlServer limitation.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?